# gulp task doesn't do concat

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm trying to first build my scss and at the end merge the result with a css file.

Here is my task

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    gulp.src('../scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe($.sass({
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/styles/'))
        .pipe($.filelog())
        .pipe($.size());

   gulp.src([
               '../public/bower_components/animate.css/animate.css',      
               '../public/styles/styles.css'
            ], {base: '.'})
        .pipe($.concat('../public/styles/styles.css'))
        .pipe($.filelog())
        .pipe($.size());
});
```

Now the end result is a css file which only contains my scss css, it seems that the animate css is ignored. Any suggestions what I do wrong here ?

Comment: You should be concatenating stylesheets at the sass level. Do some @import statements in your main .scss file. Also, change the files extension for all files you are importing to .scss

Comment: The animate.css comes from bower, so I cannot just include it. `@import` doesn't copy the content from the imported file into the other! Anyway, how hard can it be to merge two files ?

Comment: just do it, you are doing it weird. http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5

Comment: I checked it out, but it only describes importing **scss**, not css

Comment: You are right! What an important missing feature especially for things like bower. There has been a ticket to enable this feature - https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/556/. I would either switch to Less/Stylus (unreasonable I know), or use something like this gulp plugin - https://github.com/yuguo/gulp-import-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice you to have a look at [event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream), you can end up with something like so for your `styles` task with a much cleaner syntax :

```
es = require('event-stream');

gulp.task('styles', function () {

  var _css = gulp.src(['../public/bower_components/animate.css/animate.css',      
                      '../public/styles/styles.css'], {base: '.'});

  var _sass = gulp.src('../scss/styles.scss')
               .pipe($.sass({ errLogToConsole: true }))
               .pipe($.autoprefixer('last 2 versions'));

  return es.merge(_sass, _css)
           .pipe($.concat('styles.css'))
           .pipe($.filelog())
           .pipe($.size())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles/'));

});
```

Comment: Just one other question, if I move the beginning of the path to the base: `['bower_comp.....', '...'], {base: '../public/'}`, it doesn't include those files anymore. Any suggestions what goes wrong ?

Comment: Don't really know at the moment, but if you really struggle open a new question. I advice you to have your `Gulpfile` at the root of your project, so you don't have to go up in your paths, you've access all of your files, sounds better to me.

Comment: This is a meteor project, and then you can't just do that (AFAIK), so I have all my gulp files in a directory called `.gulp`. I'll open a new question for that issue if I can't solve it, thnx!

Comment: Just found the solution, it turns out that the paths in the array need to begin with a `/`